# Is this 60's Atlanta airport security picture geniuine, and if so, what is happening here?

Tags: aircraft, travel, crime, 1960s, 1970s

Following the advice I got from the user Semaphore I would like to split my original airport security [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46264/did-airports-have-security-checks-before-the-1970s) into separate parts and go into a bit more detail in regards to what I would like to know about those pictures, and this one in particular.

[image: https://78.media.tumblr.com/5dab872ee5afc9a2fc1dec1cae002762/tumblr_inline_nonupcZr7G1qce1ag_500.png]

> Just hate going through airport security with all those new gizmos, c. 1960.
>
> Taken at Atlanta Municipal Airport during testing for their first security instruments.

That was before the first hijacking of a commercial flight in the US, if I am not mistaken!

Do you think it is real?

It seems to be taken at that time indeed, but... What sort of device would it be technically? The graphs on the paper show some repeating cycles... And the two vertical bars in there do not really look like a magnetometer to me. Also I do not think such things were even being developed back in those days as something for use on humans...

Even if the picture postdates the first hijackings, my impression is still that before 1968, both the airlines and the passengers viewed them as more of an inconvenience, rather than terrorism act or something. So, everyone was opposed to the idea of screening passengers, as that would just scare them off, and lead to costs for the carriers. Federal agents could be deployed on flights upon request from 1961... Apparently it was considered sufficient back then really. On top of that I do not think Atlanta was a place very popular with hijackers...

Also the facial expression of the woman and the other photographer in the background suggest that it was something staged. I feel it could be that someone just found it, and said it was airport security as a joke or a prank, because that was the first thing they thought upon seeing this...

The picture is circulated in the web with this description, but I could not find any more information on it. And that just makes me even more interested to know what is actually happening there.

If anyone knows what these things are all about, and how it used to work back then, I would absolutely love to hear that. So any explanations strongly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: The hairstyle and dress print certainly seem more late 1960s if not early 1970s to me.

Comment: @JonCuster. If that is late sixties or early seventies that would certainly make a lot more sense, but would the trousers and ties look different then? The equipment and the whole scene are still strange though.

Comment: [First Amierican hijacking was 1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_hijackings).  "Prior to the 1970s American airports had minimal security arrangements to prevent acts of terrorism. Measures were introduced starting in the late 1960s after several high-profile hijackings." [Airport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_security#United_States).

Comment: Not sure why OP omitted this information, but as I wrote previously, the photo is from the Atlanta History Center. It's taken by a photographer called Bill Wilson and the description says the model is named Linda Fay. Perhaps a good palce to start would be to ask either the Center or the Airport.

Comment: @Semaphore I did originally post here the link that you gave me as a source of the picture. I guess that information was lost when Malandy later inserted the photo into the post directly. Again, I did not mean to omit anything.

Comment: Also, how would you contact an airport, about something like this?

Comment: Write them a polite email and profess to be an airport historian researching the introduction of security measures. But I would start with the Atlanta History Center since they appear to be the physical source of the photo and may either know more or know someone who might know more.

Comment: @Semaphore Sorry about the several comments in a row. One can not edit their comments after five minutes so there is no way to add some information an hour later. :) I do try to fill up the comment character limit when posting a lot of text at once though. Can you please tell me where you have found the extra information on Linda Fay?

Answer (score 3):

Magnetometer technology certainly existed back then and could easily have been packaged in two poles like that.  I'd guess that they were a fairly low-frequency resonant circuit where the field sort of just sits there between the two antennae humming quietly and happily as long as there's no metal in the middle. If metal comes through, the resonance is disrupted and the current changes.  The strip-chart recorder would be displaying the current and would show a blip characteristic of the amount and type of metal and the speed of movement.  I can't say for sure that that's what it is, but it certainly could be.

There would be years of testing before anything went into production and use.

OTOH, I agree that the picture looks staged.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am certainly not saying the technology did not exist, just that it was not meant for this purpose. When metal detectors became compulsory in 72, they would initially make them out of loggers metal detectors, used to find broken tools in wood... What are the cycles on the graph though? Is the frequency that low? I guess in that case one could really easily walk through between the impulses there. Also, the poles seem to be attached to a metal fence, and even these days, many metal detectors do not work properly, when placed adjacent to each other or metal objects.

Comment: On top of that, on the accepted pictures of airport metal detectors, even the most compact models, are a lot bigger and more bulky than this, and that was ten years later.

Comment: Good points.  First, all I can see is a squiggly line with irregular wiggles.  This is what I'd expect to see if you're looking at something like the current flowing in a resonant circuit. The whole point is to tune the circuit so it's nearly unstable -- that way some metal in the field will cause big swings that are obvious.  In the mean  time, with no metal, it wiggles and wobbles. The frequency is RF, you can't squeeze between the cycles! The fluctuations you see are small variations in the strength of the RF field.

Comment: You;re right, of course, that the metal detectors they wound up using in airports work differently. Resonant field systems do work -- I believe that's how the metal detectors used by treasure hunters work -- but I'd  not be surprised to learn that other techniques turned out to be better. (If for no other reason than that the two poles arrangement probably causes the field to spread pretty widely which adds noise and decreases sensitivity to actual weapons.)

Comment: Ok, now I can see the wiggles on the line. I was originally referring to the big spikes that seem to repeat every so often. Yes, they are not identical, like heartbeats or something, but still similar to each other. There appears to be no distinctive feature, which could be a reaction to her going through.

Comment: If only someone could find some description or reference to it in some proper reliable source... Or, maybe, by pure chance, someone has the pictures, that were taken by the other photographer... Then we would not have to guess. There are two of what seem to be some signs, but both are facing the other way.

Comment: @KitSmith Uh, I already did give you a "proper reliable source" last time - its from the Atlanta History Center. Why not put the information in your question, to let people trying to help you know where to start? FYI the photographer died in 1993, and I believe so did the model a few years ago.

Comment: @Semaphore Wait, Atlanta History Center actually provides more info on it? I did not realise that, thought it was just the picture there. Well, that was not intentional, I did not mean to hide information from anyone, of course.

Comment: @Semaphore Is [this](http://album.atlantahistorycenter.com/cdm/ref/collection/Wilson/id/534) the link you are referring to? That just gives more information on the picture itself, I meant information on the instrument, and this testing they were doing. The thing about this is, it is often quoted on the web that New Orleans airport was the very first in the US to set up some security checkpoints in July 70. Kennedy got some in early August, a plane got hijacked days later, when an armed guy walked right past a distracted guard, so newspapers recorded the fact that it was there.

Comment: Yet I can find no information about this Atlanta thing, even though it seems to be earlier. By the way, how do you know about the model, seems to be nothing other than the name there, and Google does not really find anything about her either?

Comment: @KitSmith You really need to stop posting several comments in a row like this; please at least use up to the word limit of each comment to reduce clutter. Anyway, the point is that the *literal, physical source of the photo is the Atlanta History Center*, and so there's a chance they know more about the history or can tell you who to ask.